# Session information missing from exported firebase data to Big Query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I seem to be missing session related information to the events that gets exported from Firebase to Big Query. More specifically, a unique identifier of each session (`ga_session_id`) and an ordinal number of the session count specific to the user that generates the events (`ga_session_number`).

All though they are not part of the [export schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), they can be found in the documentation [elsewhere](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9191807?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) and a recent [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html) showing queries where they use these missing fields.

Do I have to enable something in order for them to start showing up in the event_params of my firebase analytics events or are these things not yet implemented? If not, is there any information on when this will happen?

edit: I'm using the Firebase Unity SDK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

With this query I get the expected results:

```sql
SELECT event_params.value.int_value AS session_id
FROM `your table`, UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params
WHERE event_params.key = "ga_session_id"
GROUP BY 1
```

Note that in the blogpost query-example they use event_params.value.**string**_value which does not give any results

You also need to have the right SDK version (update from December)

Comment: Thanks for suggest answer! What SDK version exactly? And is it for all platforms (I'm using Firebase Unity SDK)? Looking through the release notes and cannot seem to find information on these new features.

Comment: That may be different then. For the Android SDK it should be part of the December 3 version (firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). However, I just noticed that for one single app version I have a user count that is a lot higher than session count, so apparently not for all users the ga_session_id is set. I have already raised a ticket at Firebase support about this, so I hope to have better answers later.